# Can you have children in Skyrim?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

Is it possible to have children in Skyrim?

Comment: Don't believe so, Bethesda's never been big on normal life stuff, kinda surprised they allowed people to get married in this Skyrim. If you want kids, you should go about getting them the old fashioned way... or better yet, play fable and just kill the runts when you get tired of them(evil character of course).

Comment: I've edited your question to make it acceptable on the site. Your original post was very hard to understand. Please take the time to read our [FAQ](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/faq).

Comment: Voting to close as per [this meta](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/3198/can-i-do-x-questions)

Comment: What have you found so far? What problem are you trying to solve in game by getting an answer to this?

Answer (score 21):

The family interaction you can have with your spouse are;

- to get the lovers comfort bonus
- to get some money from a home shop
- for a daily meal

Beyond that there is no interaction you can have with your spouse. And no sex out of marriage either, this is a wholesome fun game about slaying dragons.

Comment: ...and beheadings, among other disturbing violent imagery.

Comment: Many of you are saying it isn't possible to have a child or it's a mod but that's not possible. It's an achievement on the Xbox 360 called proud parent and the description is "adopt a child"

Comment: The reason for the achievement is because of Hearthfire in which you will be able to adopt a child. Currently, you still can't.

Answer (score 11):

**Yes**, with the [Hearthfire DLC](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Hearthfire).

Some of its features:

- Ability to [adopt](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Adoption) up to two children, who will move into your house.
- Interact and play games to raise your new family.
- Allow your child to keep a pet after it follows them home. Some creature followers can also be kept as a pet.
- If you wish to adopt children without moving into a new home, you may add a child's bedroom to an already purchased home in a major city.

<sup>[Source: UESP wiki, "Skyrim - Hearthfire" article](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Hearthfire)</sup>

Answer (score 7):

You can't have your own, but you can adopt children from the Orphanage in Riften using [this mod](http://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=10338).

There is also a [video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dB6ofc1_sl8) showing how it's done.

Personally didn't try it myself, but looks like it cause the child you adopt to live in your home and act as a follower - roaming around the house, sitting and eating.

Not much, but better than nothing! :)

Answer (score 2):

There is also this mod called [Clover the orphan](http://skyrim.nexusmods.com/mods/14373) that adds a girl named Clover the orphan and you can pick her up at the orphanage just make sure you either have no followers at the time or a mod that allows for more followers otherwise she will not join you.

Answer (score 2):

It is not possible at the current time in Skyrim. But on September 3,  2012 an expansion pack is being released which allows you to build a house from scratch an actually own land. It also includes the option of having children.

Answer (score 1):

No, it is not possible to have children in Skyrim. Aside from marrying and having your spouse cook dinner for you, there is decidedly limited spousal interaction. If you are using a PC, you can download [this mod](http://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=10338&searchtext=child%20adoption) which will allow you to adopt children from Riften, if you really want a little brat.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can not have children in vanilla Skyrim.